# Создание установщика на C++

Tags: c++, массивы, windows, visual-studio, динамические-массивы

Сразу скажу что я начал совсем  недавно изучать C++. И я хочу сделать простой установщик файлов. Я хочу сделать что-то по типу RuntimePack, но только тут будет намного больше всего. В идеале надо чтобы программа узнавала разрядность системы, и в случае если система x32, то устанавливала только в System32, а вот на x64 устанавливала и в System32 и в SysWOW64. Можно даже консольное приложение, главное чтобы выполняло работу.

1. Проверить разрядность, и в x32 установить только в одну папку, а в x64 сразу в две
2. Желательно спросить у пользователя уверен ли он(например Y\N)
3. Установить файлы либо в одну папку, либо в две в зависимости от разрядности
4. Спросить у пользователя хочет ли он перезагрузиться, и если хочет то перезагрузить ПК

Вроде-бы всё. Также не мешало бы узнать как сделать например массив из имён всех .dll и .ocx файлов(а их больше 700) и все эти значения по очереди зарегистрировать с помощью regsvr32.

Например есть три файла. one.dll, two.dll, three.ocx. Надо чтобы все эти три файла автоматически(чтобы не пришлось писать это вручную в коде) добавились в массив "a" и по очереди подставлялись в regsvr32. Например поставил установку, ушёл от компа, а он сам запускает подряд regsvr32 one.dll, regsvr32 two.dll, regsvr32 three.ocx.

Возможно всё это реализовать в одной программе, ну или хотя-бы сделать несколько программ и работать с ними по очереди в %TEMP% автоматически?

Если что:
Язык: C++
IDE: Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Примеры InnoSetup и NSIS показывают, что да, это возможно. Другое дело, что маловероятно, что это (делать свой установщик, когда существуют эти двое с приятными лицензиями) имеет какой-то практический смысл, кроме смысла научиться делать установщики.

Comment: Хотелки вы свои описали, но непонятно, в чем ваш вопрос.

Comment: Слишком много вопросов в одной теме. Разбейте задачу на части и задавайте по одному конкретному вопросу. Например, первый вопрос: как узнать разрядность системы Windows? И т. д PS: Спрашивать у пользователя Y/N - зависит от типа приложения. Сперва определитесь, будет это консолька или ГУЙ (и какой именно)